# wso2 unable to install features for I/O Error while copying

Tags: centos, p2, wso2

I'm trying to install new features on `wso2 Carbon version 4.0.1`
I'm on a VMWare Virtual Machine running `CentOS 6.3`

I followed these steps

1. Download of the binary version of `wso2carbon-4.0.1 (wso2carbon-4.0.1)`
2. extracted under path /opt/wso2/
3. went into `/opt/wso2/wso2carbon-4.0.1/bin and edited wso2server.sh` adding these lines:

   ```
   JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0.x86_64/jre/
   PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
   export PATH
   export JAVA_HOME
   ```
4. run the server with ./wso2server.sh

   the server runs fine
5. Downloaded file p2-repo.zip for version 4.0.1 and unzipped in /opt/wso2/
6. Logged into `https://localhost:9443/carbon` and added a new repository in the features->Repository Management pointing to file:///opt/wso2/p2-repo
7. went to available features clicked on "Find Features"
8. From the list I've selected "API Manager" then clicked on Install Features.

At this point a window telling that a provisioning error has occured.
The terminal where `wso2server.sh` was running says:

```
[2012-09-24 18:27:23,118] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.feature.mgt.services.prov.ProvisioningAdminService} -  Error occured while performing provisioning action
org.wso2.carbon.feature.mgt.core.ProvisioningException: An error occurred while configuring the installed items
  session context was:(profile=WSO2CarbonProfile, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Configure, operand=null --> [R]org.jaggeryjs.server.feature.group 0.9.0.ALPHA1, action=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.touchpoint.natives.actions.CopyAction).
  I/O Error while copying /opt/wso2/wso2carbon-4.0.1/repository/components/features/org.jaggeryjs.server_0.9.0.ALPHA1/modules - see details.
    Source: /opt/wso2/wso2carbon-4.0.1/repository/components/features/org.jaggeryjs.server_0.9.0.ALPHA1/modulesdoes not exists
    at org.wso2.carbon.feature.mgt.core.util.ProvisioningUtils.performProvisioningAction(ProvisioningUtils.java:77)
    at org.wso2.carbon.feature.mgt.core.util.ProvisioningUtils.performProvisioningAction(ProvisioningUtils.java:86)
    at org.wso2.carbon.feature.mgt.services.prov.ProvisioningAdminService.performProvisioningAction(ProvisioningAdminService.java:278)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCUtil.invokeServiceClass(RPCUtil.java:212)
    at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(RPCMessageReceiver.java:117)
    at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.java:40)
    at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver$AsyncMessageReceiverWorker.run(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:271)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Can you try with (http://dist.wso2.org/p2/carbon/releases/4.0.1/) as the repository URL? it may be an error in extracted p2-repo. It was working fine in Ubuntu. I do not have cent os to reproduce and see. Try online p2 repo and see if the error is still there.

Answer (score 0):

I moved to **Ubuntu 10.04 x64** and **openjdk**.

**OpenJDK version is: java version "1.6.0_24" OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.11.4) (6b24-1.11.4-1ubuntu0.10.04.1)**. **OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0-b12, mixed mode)** ... now features are installing fine using the same p2-repo.zip as above!

Thank you Artemix for your suggestions!